# How can I fix this Arango (Golang) AQL Query to use an Index?

Tags: go, arangodb, aql

Hey I'm having this issue trying to use an index in AQL. I tried checking out the documentation and other SO question but couldn't find any examples.

This is my code in Golang:

```
query := `
  LET results = FLATTEN(
    FOR doc IN @@collectionName01
    FILTER @brand == doc.name
    RETURN doc.cars)
  FOR doc IN @@collectionName02
    FILTER results ANY IN doc.cars
    RETURN doc
  USE INDEX @carIndex`

bindVars := map[string]interface{}{
  "@collectionName01": Brand_Collection,
  "brand":              brand,
  "@collectionName02": Car_Collection,
  "carIndex": Car_Index,
}
```

But I keep getting this error that I can't figure out:
`AQL: syntax error, unexpected identifier, expecting end of query string near 'USE INDEX @carIndex\n\t\t...' at position (while parsing)`

Any help or direction would be incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to use `OPTIONS {indexHint: @carIndex}`

```
query := `
  LET results = FLATTEN(
    FOR doc IN @@collectionName01
    FILTER @brand == doc.name
    RETURN doc.cars)
  FOR doc IN @@collectionName02 OPTIONS {indexHint: @carIndex}
    FILTER results ANY IN doc.cars
    RETURN doc
bindVars := map[string]interface{}{
  "@collectionName01": Brand_Collection,
  "brand":              brand,
  "@collectionName02": Car_Collection,
  "carIndex": Car_Index,
}
```

However I was informed by the Arango team that `ANY IN` cannot utilize a regular index. This is only supported by ArangoSearch. So the proper way of writing this is:

```
query := `
  FOR doc1 IN @@collectionName01 FILTER @brand == doc1.name
    FOR doc2 IN @@collectionName02
    FILTER doc1.cars ANY IN doc2.cars
    RETURN doc2`
bindVars := map[string]interface{}{
  "@collectionName01": Brand_Collection,
  "brand":              brand,
  "@collectionName02": Car_Collection,
}
```